# Can i create Bootstrap cards without bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

Can i create constructs like the Cards from Bootstrap, using just Jquery, Jquery UI, without Bootstrap?

What i need the cards to do is have a Header, Body and Footer,like below
[image]

If yes, I would really appreciate a working example.
I can't use Bootstrap because it disrupts some animations that I'm using in the code.

Comment: Yeah of course you can, just code it from scratch. It's quite simple and SO isn't a place asking for code to be written for you

Comment: You don't need jQuery to create a card though, just CSS

Comment: If you are a web developer, you can easily create it yourself from HTML/CSS from scratch. It will not disrupts your animations.

Comment: Maybe i was a bit unclear. I was looking for a card that has the same formatting as the default bootstrap card. Same background-colors, font-size, font-family.

Comment: Yeah so code it from scratch, it's 3 divs with text styles

Comment: I don't understand why you would downvote a question before clarifying what I meant. Of course it's easy to use divs, that's not what I was asking i can write the code on my own, I was looking for the formatting used in the original Bootstrap Cards so i can replicate it... If you don't know it don't askwer, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question to include css and html tags rather than frameworks.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you can't use view source or the developer console to see what styling is applying to the button that you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SCSS you can use the bootstrap github to find the source code and modify to your needs. You'll need to trace mixins and variables to replace them with your own values.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_card.scss

Answer (score 0):

This is a codepen of how I created a bootstrap card without bootstrap, and encapsulated it in a Jquery function.

Few things you should not do:

-don't use `display:table, with display: row`. If you do, borders will not display correctly, unless you also use `border-collapse: collapse`, in which case `border-radius` will not work. Use display flex instead.

https://codepen.io/dumitrudan608/pen/eEdPVG